# Formatting Excel Output of Crystal Reports with Multiple Subqueries

Tags: crystal-reports

I've put together a summary report in Crystal Reports 2013 that has about 10-12 subreports. Each subreport is a fairly basic query that produces one or several lines rows and columns of data. I'm using SAP's Central Management Console to produce the reports, with the output an Excel output.

My problem is that my excel output is coming out unstandardized i.e. random extra empty rows and columns, data and header mismatches, different widths of rows and columns, etc.

I've been messing around with the formatting setting w/in Crystal Reports (standardizing size and shape of subqueries on the preview screen, supressing empty areas, etc.) but can't come close to getting the Excel output to look the way I want.

Is there a specific export formatting function/area within Crystal Reports that will allow me to design the export in the way I'd like? And if not, are there any ways to format multiple subqueries w/in Crystal Reports so their format in an Excel export is uniform?

Answer (score 0):

If i really understood your issue, you have troubles with the alignment of data, cells and stuff like that in the spreadsheet, is it correct?

If so, the solution is to review the align of your fields in the report. It is very boring. You can use some functionalitis like:

1. right click a field and use "align to grid"
2. select two fields, right click and use "left align" and "top align"
3. change the property "gridsize" of the "report" to a higher value and use the keyboard to position the fields.
4. Avoid empty spaces between field at most.
5. Keep your eyes on the rulers.

Furthermore, check the version of Crystal Reports you are using. There is a good improvement about it from version 11 to 13.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to Excel seems a bit qwerky because the same steps do not necessarily work for all reports (my experience at least).  Keep this in mind when reading the following steps.  Perform the following steps on both the detail(footer if using grouping) and header rows where applicable:

1. Choose driver “Microsoft Excel(97-2003)”
2. Make sure the header and detail sections have no spaces in between the columns
3. Make sure the header and detail column boxes align perfectly (should see red crosses when alignment is correct).
4. Select all fields on the row, right-click, align to top (if this does try aligning to grid)
5. Right-click to the left of the detail columns and “Select All Section Objects”
6. Right-click in the same location and choose “Arrange Lines” then “Fit Section”
7. Perform steps 4 & 5 on the header columns as well
8. Open Section Expert, select “Suppress Blank Section” for all unused sections
9. If none of the above work, use driver “Microsoft Excel (97-2003) (Data Only) “

- Headers will still appear in the report but will not be in bold